# Android 3.0: Create a custom menu with submenu

Tags: android

I am working with Android 3.0.

I am trying to build a custom menu in the action bar that has sub-menus in it.
Anybody has the XML hierarchy that should be written?

Comment: I suspect that submenus are no longer supported, but that's just a guess. Have you seen any Android 3.0 apps that have submenus with their action bar?

Comment: I've worked with some applications of Android 3.0, I must say that I didn't see any submenu, but it is supported in the options menu of Android 3.0 and I need it in my custom menu for my app.

Answer (score 0):

`<item>` elements can contain `<menu>` elements.  I've only tested this on ICS but it looks like it should work on Honeycomb as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_dropdown"
        android:title="More" 
        android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
      <item android:id="@+id/menu_one" android:title="One" />
      <item android:id="@+id/menu_two" android:title="Two" />
    </menu>
  </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this is not a sub-menu, what you gave me is an item that creates a menu with 2 items. I meant that one of these 2 items will show another menu.